# C++: Including libraries, multiple definitions (ARPACK++)

Tags: c++, static-libraries, arpack

I'm currently trying to work with other C++ libraries like ARPACK++ and got trouble with multiple definitions within the include folder of ARPACK++.
This is my compiling line which includes several libraries i need:

```
 g++ -g -Dlinux -I/home/LapEVSol/arpack++/include -I/usr/local/include/g++-3 -o main main.cc Basis.cc IntegrationRule.cc Matrix.cc Mesh.cc PDE.cc /home/LapEVSol/arpack++/libsuperlu_4.3.a  /home/LapEVSol/arpack++/libarpack.a /home/LapEVSol/arpack++/liblapack.a /home/LapEVSol/arpack++/librefblas.a /home/LapEVSol/arpack++/libgfortran.a  -lm
```

And the Compiler is handing me this error out:

```
Matrix.cc: In member function ‘ARluSymMatrix<double>* CSCMatrix::CreateARluSymMatrix()’:
Matrix.cc:338:25: warning: address of local variable ‘MatrixName’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
ARluSymMatrix<double> MatrixName(rows, nnz, entries, rowIndex, colPointer, 'L');
                     ^
/tmp/ccb6n5wo.o: In function `void std::_Destroy_aux<true>::__destroy<int*>(int*, int*)':
/home/LapEVSol/arpack++/include/arerror.h:163: multiple definition of `ArpackError::Set(ArpackError::ErrorCode, std::string const&)'
/tmp/ccR5YW3o.o:/home/LapEVSol/arpack++/include/arerror.h:163: first defined here
/tmp/ccb6n5wo.o: In function `void std::_Destroy_aux<true>::__destroy<int*>(int*, int*)':
/home/LapEVSol/arpack++/include/arerror.h:163: multiple definition of `ArpackError::code'
/tmp/ccR5YW3o.o:/home/LapEVSol/arpack++/include/arerror.h:163: first defined here
/tmp/ccpDlwxP.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Mesh::Node>::new_allocator()':
/home/LapEVSol/arpack++/include/arerror.h:163: multiple definition of `ArpackError::Set(ArpackError::ErrorCode, std::string const&)'
/tmp/ccR5YW3o.o:/home/LapEVSol/arpack++/include/arerror.h:163: first defined here
/tmp/ccpDlwxP.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Mesh::Node>::new_allocator()':
/home/LapEVSol/arpack++/include/arerror.h:163: multiple definition of `ArpackError::code'
/tmp/ccR5YW3o.o:/home/LapEVSol/arpack++/include/arerror.h:163: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

It's a bit weird, since the include header "*arerrorh.h*" is wrapped inside a proper:

```
 #ifndef ARERROR_H
 #define ARERROR_H
 ...
 #endif
```

Could it be that i'm doing something wrong in the linking or compiling part? Because that's pretty much the part i'm least confident at. I would be glad if someone could tell me what i'm doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would worry more about the `warning: address of local variable ‘MatrixName’ returned` for now. Yes, the multiple definition is at link time, so the guard define won't help you with that

Answer (score 0):

The header `arerror.h` has an error in it. Put `inline` in the definition of `ArpackError::Set` function. Also, *please*, fix the `CSCMatrix::CreateARluSymMatrix` method, which is returning the address of a local variable.

Comment: I fixed that part. Now the error is a bit shorter, but still there: /tmp/ccOcpFbY.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Mesh::Node>::new_allocator()':
/home/LapEVSol/arpack++/include/arrseig.h:33: multiple definition of `ArpackError::code'

Comment: @Log7 which part did you fix? I suggested 2 fixes, one for the error and one for the warning

Comment: @Log7 the `ArpackError::code` definition should be in a .cpp file, not in a header. Make it a .cpp file for it and put it in there.